# finding the general solution to inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

$$u'' + 4u= 8x^2 + 13e^{3x} + 16\cos2x.$$

So to find the general solution I first have to find the homogeneous and particular solutions and then general solution will be $u= u_h + u_p$.

So characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 + 4 = 0 \implies \lambda = 2i, -2i$.

So homogeneous solution is $u_h = Ae^{2ix}+ Be^{-2ix} = \cos2x + D\sin2x$.

But then I got stuck on the particular solution. Usually I would try different things to see what works but I'm unsure what to try here. Any ideas? And how do I know what to look for when trying out particular solutions?

Comment: See method of undetermined coefficients. To get for example $13e^{3x}$ on the right side, try $u(x)=Ae^{13x}$ and find an appropriate coefficient $A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Let
$$u_p= Ax^2 + Be^{3x} + Cx\cos2x + Dx\sin2x$$

Comment: How does one find that ansatz?

Comment: Each parts need a coefficient. $A$ for $x^2$, $B$ for $e^{3x}$ and $\cdots$

Comment: For $\cos$ part, we know $\cos2x$ is one of general solution, so we should  add $x$ factor behind it!

Comment: understood, but why did you add the "$Dx$sin$2x$" to $u_p$?

Comment: We must consider all possible cases.

Comment: So why not just $D$sin$2x$ ?

Comment: because $\sin2x$ is one of general solutions.

Comment: ah of course thankyou!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Okay so now I've tried that, it worked except I had an extra 2A from $u_{p}''$.. How do i get avoid that?

Comment: Do i just add -2A to my particular solution

Comment: It should be a number, find it with some value of $x$.

Comment: @Nosrati it's $Ax^2+K$ not $Ax^2$

Comment: Let me try!.....

Comment: @Isham so do i always need to add +K to my $u_p$ just in case?

Comment: @sam here you need $Ax^2+K$ as a particular solution  Try it sam and you sill see ...You will get values for A and K...

Comment: Yep when I add +K to the particular solution @Nosrati gave me it works! Thanks both of you

Comment: you're welcome @sam  the particular solution provided by Nosrati should work fine except for $Ax^2$

Comment: So when @Isham said that, it is definitely correct...thanks isham.

Comment: Actually it was a group work :)